# How can I add elements in random indices of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have generated a 4 by 4 array. Then I have generated a 1D array of 1s and 0s of length 8 such as [0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]. I then generated a seed that will be used to create a sample of random indices. The number of indices generated are equal to the number of elements in the message. Now I wish to add the elements of message in the indices generated which represent the locations of the indices in the 4 by 4 array. After adding the elements of the message in the indices of the 4 by 4 matrix. I wish to display the new 4 by 4 array matrix with the added elements.

```
import numpy as np  
import random  
from PIL import Image 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#array  
cover = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])

max_len = (4 * 4)  #number of elements in cover since we have a 4 by 4 array


#Generating Message
msg = np.random.randint(2, size=8)  
len_msg = len(msg)

#Generating a seed which will be used to locate where the msg will be added in the matrix
seed = 4  
print "The chosen seed is %d" % (seed)  
random.seed(seed)

#Generate Indices to be used to add in matrix
indices = random.sample(range(len_msg, max_len),len_msg)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: properly mention your question. unable to understand

Comment: Indices are the indices of the 4 by 4 array where I want to add the elements of the message. After adding the elements of the message to those indices I want to form a new array with those added data elements to the original 4 by 4 array.

Comment: I honestly cannot be more clear than that..

Comment: So, you want to flatten the first 2D array so that you can use your full range of indices, and you want to _replace_ 8 values in that flattened array with your generated values, at random indices, before reshaping back to a 2D array? Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Max_ len is the number of elements in the original matrix called cover. I have a maximum of 16 elements. Indices is an array which are 8 indices of those 16 elements in the  4 by 4 array called cover. Now I want to add the elements of the message in those indices. Am I clear now?

Comment: Did you get me now? @roganjosh

Comment: If you are working with a flattened version : `cover.ravel()[indices] = new_values`, where `new_values` would be `msg` IIUC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np

cover = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])

max_len = cover.size

msg = np.random.randint(2, size=8)  

np.random.seed(4)
indices = np.random.choice(range(max_len), msg.size, replace=False)

cover.ravel()[indices] += msg
```

Comment: Almost!! i want to add the msg to those elements of those indices not just replace them @roganjosh

Comment: Add as in `sum` at each index?

Comment: @CharlesB I have made an edit (you just need to change `=` to `+=` to modify the values at each index). This is based on my understanding of "add" here.

Comment: index 0 of the original matrix is 1 now the first index is the message is 0. i want to add 1+ 0 = 1 not replace index[0] with (message[0]) 0. And do the same for all the others. Did you get me  @roganjosh ?

Comment: @CharlesB Yes, and now it's either 1 or 2 because `msg` will either add `0` or `1` to it depending on the values chosen. My edit takes care of that.

Comment: [[ 0  2  0  0]   
 [ 0  6  1  8] 
 [ 9  0 11  1] 
 [ 0 14 15 16]]

Comment: @CharlesB then you haven't started using the code I edited 15 mins ago. I changed it so that it adds the values of msg. `[[ 2,  2,  3,  4], [ 5,  6,  8,  8], [ 9, 10, 11, 12], [14, 14, 15, 16]]`